# LDAPS not working: failed to bind to LDAP server (16.04)

Tags: ldap, tls

LDAP works fine on my machine but LDAPS does not seem to work. Tried `/etc/ldap.conf` and `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` with the Cert names to be specified with TLS_CACERTFILE & TLS_CACERT as mentioned in multiple forums and that does not seem to fix the issue. The same CA cert has been tested on my other Linux servers (CentOS, Scientific, RHEL) and they all authenticate fine with LDAPS with the given certificate and bind.

**FAILURE LOGS**

```
 04:22:57  nscd: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as <bind account> - Can't contact LDAP server
 04:22:57  nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://example:636: Can't contact LDAP server
 04:22:57  nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
 04:22:57  nscd: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as <bind account> - Can't contact LDAP server
 04:22:57  nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://example:636: Can't contact LDAP server
 04:22:57  nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
 04:22:58  nscd: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as <bind account> - Can't contact LDAP server
 04:22:58  nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://example:636: Can't contact LDAP server
 04:22:58  nscd: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
```

From [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920405/ldaps-not-working-on-my-ubuntu-machine-16-04-2-lts#comment1453909_920405):

```
# ldapsearch -x -d5 -H ldaps://example
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://example)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://example:636/??base) ...............
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP example:636
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying <IP Address>:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0 attempting to connect: connect success TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x142) TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

**LDAP CONFIGURATION**

```
# cat /etc/ldap.conf
base              o=example.com
uri               ldaps://example:636
ldap_version      3
binddn            bind account
bindpw            bind passwd
pam_password      md5
nss_base_passwd   
nss_base_shadow   
nss_base_group    
nss_base_networks 
nss_base_netgroup 
ssl on
TLS_CACERTFILE  /etc/ldap/cacerts/cacert.pem
DEBUG   1
TLS_REQCERT    demand
# cat /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ldap/cacerts/cacert.pem
TLS_REQCERT demand

BASE    o=example.com
URI     ldaps://example
```

Comment: Is the ldap server configured to provide ldaps access? If it is an OpenLDAP server, please look at `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf` if present, or the files in `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` (see `man slapd.conf`and `man slapd-config`, respective. Or try `slaptest` on the server.

Comment: Yes the LDAP server is configured for LDAPS access. The problem I face is only with my ubuntu client machines. All my other linux client machines are authenticating fine with the LDAPS.

Comment: This is what I see on the ubuntu machine.
# ldapsearch -x -d5 -H ldaps://example
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://example)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://example:636/??base)
...............
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP example:636
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying <IP Address>:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x142)
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Comment: "TLS: peer cert untrusted..." means your client does not accept the certificate of the server. You might "need to modify ldap.conf to disable certificate verification" or copy the public key of the server to the certificate list of your client; refer to the answer to https://serverfault.com/questions/653321/unable-to-connect-to-server-via-ldaps and the comments there. The certificate store is defined in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`as `TLS_CACERT`.

Comment: the same certificate is again used on all my llinux ldap client and they all seem to work fine.